# Show the combined data from two columns and displays the even-numbered columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with data in a following format

```
pin    name      scan_Time   scan_location
1      Albert    09:25:53    Office A       
1      Albert    10:26:12    Office B
2      Barry     08:26:21    Office C
2      Barry     09:21:57    Office B
2      Barry     10:31:17    Office B
2      Barry     12:21:44    Office A
3      Cantika   07:38:10    Office B
3      Cantika   10:02:28    Office A
```

I'm looking for the best query to output my data in the following format.

```
pin    name      scan_time   scan_location   routes
1      Albert    09:25:53    Office A        
1      Albert    10:26:12    Office B        Office A - Office B
2      Barry     08:26:21    Office C
2      Barry     09:21:57    Office B        Office C - Office B
2      Barry     10:31:17    Office B
2      Barry     12:21:44    Office A        Office B - Office A
3      Cantika   07:38:10    Office B
3      Cantika   10:02:28    Office A        Office B - Office A
```

How can I generate a 'routes' column that displays as above and can display only on even columns on certain 'pin'?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Query the database, read the results, determine the routes and display them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in MySQL using the following approach. See it working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/197606/15)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`pin` int, `name` varchar(7), `scan_Time` time, `scan_location` varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`pin`, `name`, `scan_Time`, `scan_location`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Albert', '09:25:53', 'Office A'),
    (1, 'Albert', '10:26:12', 'Office B'),
    (2, 'Barry', '08:26:21', 'Office C'),
    (2, 'Barry', '09:21:57', 'Office B'),
    (2, 'Barry', '10:31:17', 'Office B'),
    (2, 'Barry', '12:21:44', 'Office A'),
    (3, 'Cantika', '07:38:10', 'Office B'),
    (3, 'Cantika', '10:02:28', 'Office A')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
   pin,name,scan_time,scan_location, route
FROM (
      SELECT
            @row_num := (@row_num+1)%2  AS RowNumber
          , t1.*
          , IF((@row_num+1)%2=1,concat(@prev_value , ' ', scan_location),'') route
          , @prev_value := t1.scan_location
      FROM table1 t1
      CROSS JOIN (
              SELECT @row_num :=0,  @prev_value := ''
            ) vars
      ORDER BY pin, scan_time
     ) d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/197606/15/0)**:

```
| pin |    name | scan_time | scan_location |             route |
|-----|---------|-----------|---------------|-------------------|
|   1 |  Albert |  09:25:53 |      Office A |                   |
|   1 |  Albert |  10:26:12 |      Office B | Office A Office B |
|   2 |   Barry |  08:26:21 |      Office C |                   |
|   2 |   Barry |  09:21:57 |      Office B | Office C Office B |
|   2 |   Barry |  10:31:17 |      Office B |                   |
|   2 |   Barry |  12:21:44 |      Office A | Office B Office A |
|   3 | Cantika |  07:38:10 |      Office B |                   |
|   3 | Cantika |  10:02:28 |      Office A | Office B Office A |
```